# iPhone Bluetooth: specification of the native camera app control

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Some gadgets can control iPhone's native apps like "Muku Shuttr" can take a picture via Bluetooth without 3rd-party apps.

[http://www.amazon.com/Muku-Shuttr-Black-Samsung-Bluetooth/dp/B00GCD2MDM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GCD2MDM)

What I need to know are two things; firstly, where is the specification of Bluetooth connection to control iPhone's native apps. Take for the camera example, what kind of notifies should I send to the iPhone from my gadgets? Sencodly, is it possible to receive the Bluetooth notify on my own apps.

I need to make a remote camera app. If I can retrive the official Bluetooth notifies on my own app, I don't need to make a gadget like "Muku Shuttr" with BLE module. It is great for me.

I strongly need the information. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: With iOS, you can take a picture by clicking on the "+" button of your headset. I guess that's what's used. Maybe try with Android phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muku Shuttr sends a volume+ signal (presumably using the AVRCP profile). That it's happening via Bluetooth isn't really relevant—your app will see a volume changed event.

So your app only needs to support the use of the volume button to take pictures in the same way as Apple's native app does. Of course, it also needs to do so in a way that's acceptable to Apple...